# Extend a div right to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, scroll, fill

I know this has been asked many a time but none of the solutions given have worked for me. The rough-as-guts basic example can be seen [here](http://bloogum.net/wp_testing/test1.html) and a handy visual guide [here](http://bloogum.net/temp/emptydiv.jpg).

So it's the brown div on the left that's giving issues. It's completely empty, purely decorative, with nothing in it but the background. (The pink ones are fine, they do exactly what I tell them.) Obviously, for the brown div, making the height:100%; only stretches to the bottom of the browser window. If the content of the pink divs makes the page scroll, the brown doesn't go any further down.

**Solutions that haven't worked**

*Faux Columns*
As you can see from the handy visual guide, I've got the content divs that basically make it a side-scrolling layout--currently up to 10 divs extend out to the right by around 10,000 pixels. Since faux columns basically require making a background image with the column included, and because my backgrounds are patterns, the resulting 10,000px wide image would seriously impact load time.

*Specify pixel height of brown div*
The content divs aren't a standard height. On some pages the longest is only a few hundred pixels below the bottom of the browser window, on others it's a few thousand. Making the brown div x-thousand pixels high to cover them all is untidy and lazy and I really don't want to have to resort to that.

*dual background images*
Something I found with CSS3 is that you can set two background images for the body background. I nearly had it with this! Is there a way of specifying exact details for the separate images? (eg set whitepaper.jpg to repeat, then brownpaper.jpg to repeat-y only) If that can be done then I've got it, but so far as I can see both images have to have the same attributes, which would mean once again making the column image extend for thousands of pixels, and also make it a .png to give it transparency to see the white behind.

*Setting height of body and html to 100%*
Didn't do anything. It actually broke something in the behaving pink divs.

**The code (that matters)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
  body
{
    font-family: conquerorsans, Tahoma, verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #9e8166;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    background-color: #e6e0d5;
    background-image:url(images/layout/whitepaper.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position:top left;
}

  #top-trim
{
    position:absolute;
    left:90px;
    top:0px;
    height:20px;
    width:550px;
    background-image:url(images/layout/brownpaper.jpg);
}

#main-header
{
    position:absolute;
    left:90px;
    top:90px;
    height:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width:550px;
    background-image:url(images/layout/brownpaper.jpg);
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<header id="top-trim">
</header>

<header id="main-header">
</header>

<div style="position:absolute; top:400px; left:700px; width:20px;">
a dsg asd gf asdfg as dfg dfsag df g dfa g afd ga df ga fg a sg a g ag a ga fsa fas dg     a sfdg asd g asd ga dsg adsg as dg as g ar ga rg a g asd ads f asd f dsf asd  dsaf asd f sda fasd f ads fsd  sd dsf asdf a sdgsda f asd a ds fa sdf ads  fads f as d asdf sd a sdf asd f asdf asd f asd f ds fsda f f d ads fad sf  asd asd sd f asd f a f ds asd fa fa ss ad
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Thoughts on how it might be fixed?**
Can I set the div to be fixed when scrolling up and down, but scroll left and right?

I've come to the conclusion that this just can't be done with CSS. If it's something that can be done with javascript, jQuery or even php then I'm open to that, too. I'm brand new to these three languages though, so please be gentle!

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

First off your example doesn't work

Second off, this would be easiest to do by giving the brown `position:absolute`, style it the same way that you would float it, compensate for the margins, and give its parent `position:relative`. You did not provide CSS for me to be able to recreate it exactly to what you want, but the following demo should be all you need to implement a fix

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/svckk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed from http://bloogum.net/wp_testing/test1.html that text is insert outside

```
  <header id="main-header"><div style="width: 20px; left: 700px; top: 400px;">a dsg asd gf asdfg as dfg dfsag df g dfa g afd ga df ga fg a sg a g ag a ga fsa fas dg a sfdg asd g asd ga dsg adsg as dg as g ar ga rg a g asd ads f asd f dsf asd  dsaf asd f sda fasd f ads fsd  sd dsf asdf a sdgsda f asd a ds fa sdf ads  fads f as d asdf sd a sdf asd f asdf asd f asd f ds fsda f f d ads fad sf  asd asd sd f asd f a f ds asd fa fa ss ad
```

```
#main-header {
  background-image: url("images/layout/brownpaper.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 90px;
  width: 30px;
```

}

be careful of using position:absolute property and height shouldn't be 100% try to use auto or omit it.